# CakePHP image upload in different table

Tags: cakephp, upload

I am making product module in which image will save in different table. I am able to save vehicle_id on image table but unable to save the image name. Please give a solution if any-

**VehicleController**

```
public function newvehicle()
{
  if (empty($this->request->data)) {

  }
  else
  {
if(!empty($this->request->data['Image']['image_path']))
            {  //die('test');
                $file = $this->request->data['Image']['image_path'];
                $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
    $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'); //set allowed extensions
    //only process if the extension is valid
    if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext))
    {
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img/vehicle-images/' . $file['name']);
    $this->request->data['Image']['image_path'] = $file['name'];
    }
            }

if ($this->Vehicle->saveAll($this->request->data))
{
    $this->Session->setFlash('Vehicle Saved!');
    return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'newvehicle'));
      }
  }
}
```

**Image model**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Image extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Vehicle' => array(
            'className' => 'Vehicle',
            'foreignKey' => 'image_id'
        )
    );


}
```

**newvehicle.ctp**

```
echo $this->Html->css('custom.css');
echo $this->Form->create('Vehicle', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => 'Na`m`e'));
echo $this->Form->input('model', array('label' => 'Model'));
echo $this->Form->input('Image.image_path', array('type' => 'file'));
$status = array('1' => 'Active', '0' => 'Inactive');
echo $this->Form->input('vehicle_state', array('options' => $status, 'default' => '1', 'label' => 'Vehicle State'));
echo $this->Form->end('Create');
```

**Vehicle model**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Vehicle extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array('Image' => array
        (
            'className' => 'Image',
            'foreignKey' => 'vehicle_id'
        ));
```

Answer (score 2):

the first thing i can see is if you wanna save a value into another table thats not your "main" table,then you should actually use another model,try to use this:

> if ($this->Vehicle->Model->save($this->request->data))

edit- also your model isnt correctly setup:

> class Image extends AppModel {
>
> ```
>    public $belongsTo = array(
>        'Vehicle' => array(
>            'className' => 'Vehicle',
>            'foreignKey' => 'vehicle_id'
>        )
>    );
> ```